# magento 1.8 ajax cart URL form submission not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento-1.8

I am facing issues with magento ajax add to cart after upgrading from 1.5 to 1.8.

My form submission calls

```
<i>
onclick="http://ipaddress/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzE2Mi4yMDkuOTguMjE4Lw,,/product/651/form_key/6zHJVboCnOhdgvyG/',651".
</i>
```

[I followed this url for for ajax cart](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After clicking add to cart, I can't see an alert box with success message. Loading status image keeps on loading.

Comment: Did you find a fix? Same issue here.

Comment: Check this link, It may resolve your issue. Let me know if this does't work because too many issues with magento 1.8.0.0. you better upgrade to 1.8.1.0 now which have fixed the URL rewrte issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20236020/ajax-add-to-cart-is-not-adding-products-to-the-cart/20241472?noredirect=1#comment30196648_20241472